# Intersection in box2d not working right

Tags: c++, box2d

I'm trying to use the code here

http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/raycasting

So I can know whether a line cross a box2d object or not. It half works, in that when the line crosses the object it does show as an intersection, however, if you click before the object, it still shows as an intersection, as if it doesn't know the line stops before the object. From reading about this code, it should not do this.

Here's a screen shot of the issue.

[image]

And here's the method I'm using for the check

```
-(b2Vec2)rayCheckWithInput:(b2Vec2)p1 andX:(b2Vec2)p2
{
    b2RayCastInput input;
    input.p1 = p1;
    input.p2 = p2;
    input.maxFraction = 1;

    //check every fixture of every body to find closest
    float closestFraction = 1; //start with end of line as p2
    b2Vec2 intersectionNormal(0,0);
    //for (b2Body* b = self.world.world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext()) {
        for (b2Fixture* f = box.body->GetFixtureList(); f; f = f->GetNext()) {

            b2RayCastOutput output;
            if ( ! f->RayCast( &output, input, 0 ) )
            {
                NSLog(@"Not Intersected");
                continue;
            }
            if ( output.fraction < closestFraction ) {
                closestFraction = output.fraction;
                intersectionNormal = output.normal;

                NSLog(@"Intersected");
                NSLog(@"%f %f,", output.normal.x, output.normal.y);
                NSLog(@"%f", output.fraction);
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"Intersected2");
                NSLog(@"%f %f,", output.normal.x, output.normal.y);
                NSLog(@"%f", output.fraction);

            }
        }
    //}

    b2Vec2 intersectionPoint = p1 + closestFraction * (p2 - p1);

    NSLog(@"I point %f, %f", intersectionPoint.x, intersectionPoint.y);

    return intersectionPoint;
}
```

I can't see how in that check I can tell if the click point is before (no intersection) or beyond (intersection) the bird, it seems to give the same result regardless of either of those possibilities.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that if the 'closestFraction' remains as 1, there was no intersection. What do you mean by 'same result'? You mean you can give this function two different inputs and get exactly the same value in the intersectionPoint variable? Does not seem possible.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean, i've ran it, with giving it p1,p2 points before and beyond the  object and you get the same output.

Comment: This is tagged [C++]???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem of unit of measure: you should convert p1 and p2 coordinates (pixel or points) to box2d coordinates (meters).